# Cannot draw on Canvas unless Draw method is called from MainWindow()

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas

I'm building a heat-scatter tool for a popular game and I've ran into an issue trying to draw things onto a canvas.

In short:
I'm having a list points (coords,color) which I intend to draw on the canvas. They are the result of a long chain of irrelevant stuff, but in the end I must pass the list of points to the `DrawPoints()` method which is to visualize them.

However, upon doing so, I don't see anything being drawn (incl the SetMapImage()). It does work with the dummy points I'm creating at random in the method itself, but only if I call it from the `public MainWindow()` method. 
Trying to call it from another class's method as such...

```
MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();
mainWindow.DrawPoints(listOfPointsToDraw);
```

...does not yield results. (presuming the method is wired up properly)

I went into making my tool with WPF unprepared, and it does come back to haunt me. I'm at a loss as to what is causing this behavior, probably because I don't understand something fundamental, but I don't even know where to start reading. Any input is much appreciated but bear in mind I'm not too familiar with the subject matter.

[image: This is what it looks like when it's working properly. Otherwise, I just see the Canvas background color.]

The relevant methods are shown below.

```
public MainWindow()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                DrawPoints(); // Calling this from here draws the background image and the dummy points
                              // Calling it from elsewhere draws nothing
            }
```

...

```
public void DrawPoints()
        {
            SetMapImage();
            DrawingVisual dv = new DrawingVisual();
            using (DrawingContext dc = dv.RenderOpen())
            {

                Random rand = new Random();
                for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
                dc.DrawRectangle(Brushes.Red, null, new Rect(rand.NextDouble() * 4500, rand.NextDouble() * 4500, 10, 10));

                for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
                {
                    dc.DrawRectangle(Brushes.Red, null, new Rect(100 * i , 100 * i, 100, 100));
                }
            }
            RenderTargetBitmap rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap(4500, 4500, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
            rtb.Render(dv);
            Image img = new Image();
            img.Source = rtb;
            img.IsHitTestVisible = false;
            drawCanvas.Children.Add(img);
        }
```

Sets the background.

```
private void SetMapImage()
        {
            ImageBrush ib = new ImageBrush();
            ib.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"C:\Local Projects\CSGO Gamejam\MirageMinimapWhite.png", UriKind.Relative));
            drawCanvas.Background = ib;
        }
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your DrawPoints() method (except that my screen isn't 4500x4500).  I wired up a button to call DrawPoints(), and it works every time I click it.  I also added a call to drawCanvas.Children.Clear(), though, to remove the previous image from the canvas.  In your 1st code block, why do you create a new MainWindow object?  Do you really have multiple visible windows?  It might have been omitted from your example, but I don't see any code to actually *show* the newly created window.

Comment: Yes, thank you for pointing this out. It did throw an out of memory exception a couple of times due to this error.
Other than that 4500x4500 is used for convenience and visibility of output images, but in the program itself the canvas is within a viewbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously, creating a new MainWindow instance and calling the method on that new instance has no effect unless you actually show the new window.

Although not really clear from your question, you may want to call the method on the already existing (and shown) MainWindow instance.

You should therefore replace

```
MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();
mainWindow.DrawPoints(listOfPointsToDraw);
```

by

```
MainWindow mainWindow = (MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow;
mainWindow.DrawPoints(listOfPointsToDraw);
```

Comment: This solved the problem. Now that you pointed it out, it's obvious, but I  managed to overlook this due to my poor understanding of WPF. I know comments are not for thanks, but thank you so much! This seals the whole app for me.